# Xcode Signing - Failed to create provisioning

Tags: ios, xcode

Here's the story:

I created a free developer account to build an app for a client.

I used this info for the Identity and Signing:

[image: Screen Shot 1]

It came time to upload the app to TestFlight and to use the client's developer account.
I created the account in xcode using their apple id and updated the signing like so:

[image: Screen Shot 2]

But now I got this error.
It was clear, so I updated the Bundle Identifier to this:

[image: Screen Shot 3]

But again, now I am getting a different error, and I don't know what to do.

I do not have an iOS device to register, nor do I care to get one, since I'm not doing the testing - they are.

I did create an app in the App Store Connect, and it is set up like so:

[image: Screen Shot 4]

As you can see I created it to match the Bundle ID from before and still no luck.

Any help is greatly appreciated.  I just want to be able to get my Xcode project onto TestFlight using someone else's developer account (with their consent of course).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It needs to have at least one iOS device registered in order to create the development profile. Ask your client for the UDID of one of their devices and add that manually to the developer portal. If they don't have one handy, feel free to use: `f978c5f2e861f71b340125a4fa8d130a6254a0b3` which will work.

Alternatively, switch to manual signing and do everything manually. That's my preferred method, but some say Xcode is finally good at managing profiles etc for you.

Comment: Thank you.  adding the device cleared up everything!

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do this without a device is to turn *off* "Automatically manage signing" and manage everything at the Member Center.

You will need the distribution identity / certificate first. If the team already has one, you will need them to export it to you; otherwise you cannot upload.

Then register the app.

Then make a development certificate, and a distribution certificate for the app store, and download and install them.

Now you can archive and then export to the app store.